# Dockerize a flask authentication service

Tags: html, docker, flask, dockerfile, flask-sqlalchemy

i have some issue, i have an authentication service which work very well. I want to dockerize it, so here is the docker file

```
`From python:3.6

RUN pip install pipenv && \
    pip install flask && \
    pip install flask-sqlalchemy && \
    pip install flask-login 

RUN mkdir flask_appD

WORKDIR /flask_appD


ADD ./flask_app/auth.py flask_appD
ADD ./flask_app/db.sqlite3 flask_appD
ADD ./flask_app/__init__.py flask_appD
ADD ./flask_app/main.py flask_appD
ADD ./flask_app/models.py flask_appD

RUN mkdir templates

ADD ./flask_app/templates/base.html ./templates
ADD ./flask_app/templates/index.html ./templates
ADD ./flask_app/templates/login.html ./templates
ADD ./flask_app/templates/profile.html ./templates
ADD ./flask_app/templates/signup.html ./templates

RUN cd ..
ENV FLASK_APP "flask_appD"
ENV FLASK_DEBUG True


Expose 5000
CMD flask run`
```

The problem is that when i run the container everything seems to work nicely, but when i try to access to the localhost:5000 it does not display the result i want.

Comment: What does it display?

Comment: The connection was reset, you know the page you get when the connection is lost

Comment: How do you run your container (`docker run` parameters)? You should bind the port to your host (`-p 5000:5000`). Adding `EXPOSE` directive in the `Dockerfile` does not bind the port.

Comment: yes i did it but the problem is remaining the same

Comment: Could you share the command with which you run the container?

Comment: sudo docker run -p 5000:8000  --detach --name mycontainer autserv:latest